# Duplicated Pages Displaying Differently

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

Ok I have been having fun and games trying to sort an issue out with a website.
The home page http://www.haylockpittman.co.uk/ has been replicated to http://www.haylockpittman.co.uk/new-refurb-publish/

BUT, as you can see the images on the sub page do not align correctly like the home page.
I cannot use the home page template on the internal page as we need to change the text at the bottom and as it is set up it the text is widgetised. But we duplicated the template and renamed it.

I have compared the source codes for both pages and apart from titles the only difference is at line 142/143 where the home page calls

`<body class="home page page-id-92 page-template page-template-front-page-php singular two-column right-sidebar">`

and the internal page calls

`<body class="page page-id-2118 page-template page-template-renorefub-php singular two-column right-sidebar">`

The problem is I don't want the images on every internal page so I am wary about what I need to change. I assume I need to add a new class or div id and call it. But I am pretty novice at this and the original designer wont help so any advice would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Home page has CSS rules for '.home #outer #left' but the second doesn't (as it doesn't have the .home class on the body)

Add in extra CSS rules to apply the CSS to the same DIV on the second page.

Use Firebug/Developer Tools etc next time :)